# No merge conflicts -> broken game

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm fairly new to git and I'm having trouble fixing an old mistake. I branched an older commit and made some changes on that branch. Then I tried merging into my develop branch, and there were no merge conflicts. When I go to my game, it is broken. I thought the whole point of git was to prevent issues like this. What should I do?

I have tried this multiple times. With the other times, there sometimes was merge conflicts.

Comment: Unless you make changes to parts of code in the branch and these same parts are changed in future commits (commits after the older commit), you will not get a merge conflict. An `interactive rebase` is a cleaner alternative for this.

Comment: While uncommon, it is possible that a silent merge could result in a build not working.  You need to just check for this, and maybe make a new small commit to clean things up.

Comment: git is version control. It can’t magically prevent “breaking games.” It does exactly what you want it to do. You haven’t explained how it’s broken. Can’t compile? Won’t run? Crashes when running? I could write all kinds of things that “break” the program and git wouldn’t know about it.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought the whole point of git was to prevent issues like this. What should I do?

The fact there is no merge conflict simply means the part you have fixed was not modified in the develop branch: your merge simply copied your fix over to said branch content.
(For Unity, see "[Building and Testing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.tiny@0.13/manual/building-and-testing.html)" for Tiny Mode, or "[Writing and executing tests in Unity Test Runner](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlaymodeTestFramework.html)" for regular projects, or "[Building your Unity game to an Android device for testing](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-android-device-testing) ")

What you should do is then put in place a local build process and [basic smoke tests](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/smoke-testing/) in order to check everything is still working, *before* pushing your develop branch to a remote hosting service, where your game reside.